# Calling the Comment.Replies property (Word) to Customize CopyCommentsToExcel()

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Need to get comments and replies to comments from word using VBA to excel, with any child replies to the parent comment in same excel cell.

Currently using the tried and true method, but asking for help calling the replies object to insert these into same cell. Document in question is hundreds of pages with thousands of comments/replies, so prefer doing this in VBA verus after the fact with excel formulas.

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
    .Cells(2, 1).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Parent
    .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 1).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Index
    .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 2).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Reference.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Reference.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
    .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 4).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Range
    .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 5).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial
    .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 6).Formula = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    '        .Cells(i + 1, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Parent
    '        .Cells(i + 1, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Application
    '        .Cells(i + 1, 7).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Author
```

The way above is written, I can't plan/visualize how to merge .Parent and .Child as one cell, then loop to next.

Answer (score 0):

Add a module to your project in Word VBE and add the below UDF to it:

```
Function GetComments() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim oComms As Comments: Set oComms = ThisDocument.Comments
    Dim iComm As Long
    Dim dComs As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dComs = New Scripting.Dictionary     '<-- Requires reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
    Dim sParentText As String

    ' Loop to go through all comments in current document
    For iComm = 1 To oComms.Count

        ' Get the parent text
        sParentText = oComms.Item(iComm).Scope.Text

        ' Check if dictionary already has a key with parent text
        If dComs.Exists(sParentText) Then
            ' Key exists so add current comment at the end
            dComs(sParentText) = dComs(sParentText) & vbCrLf & oComms.Item(iComm).Range.Text
        Else
            ' Key doesnt exist so create a new key
            dComs.Add sParentText, oComms.Item(iComm).Range.Text
        End If

    Next

    ' Set return value
    Set GetComments = dComs

End Function
```

You can now call the above UDF like so:

```
Sub TestComments()
    Dim dComs As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim oKey As Variant

    ' Call UDF to get all comments from current doc
    Set dComs = GetComments

    ' Loop just to show the comments (NOT need at runtime)
    For Each oKey In dComs.Keys
        MsgBox dComs(oKey)
    Next

End Sub
```

`GetComments` returns a dictionary of all comments in the document with replies listed in new line in the same key. You can than add these to cells in Excel

Comment: Thanks for the working function, praise to you and UDFs. I still can't conceptualize how above gets integrated with the existing code to generate the same table format as before. Commment.count is one dynamic range, of "x" records versus dComs.Keys is "y" range. It won't map. Sorry for being dense here.

Comment: You do not mention in your question anything about keeping the same format. Your requirement was to have all Parent and any child comments (replies) in the same cell. UDF does that and returns a `Dictionary` object. You can loop through each key in the dictionary and copy them in cells in Excel